# Generate password tokens

Tags: javascript, html, passwords, token

If I click the generate button I want the following passwords to appear "abcd"  "1234" "!@#$" in the three empty boxes but I missed my class about this lesson and when I tried to watch youtube videos about it I get confused so can anyone help me on How to put the passwords  "abcd"  "1234" "!@#$" in the 3 empty boxes if I press the generate button? Thank you in advance

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <h1><center>Hi! there, to enter to our website please generate your Three(3) password token and use it to Enter<center></h1>
    </head>
    <script>
    var counter=3;
    function validate()
    {
        while(counter>=1)
        {
            var token1="abcd";
            var token2="1234";
            var token3="!@#$";
            var checkToken=document.getElementById("getToken").value;
            if(checkToken===token1 || checkToken===token2)
            {
                document.write("<center>password correct. Please click the link:");
                document.write('<br> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SLU.LJHS">Check our site</a>');
            }
            else
            {
                counter=counter-1;
                alert("Incorrect password!\n\n Attempts left: "+counter);
                if(counter==0)
                {
                document.write("please contact our security team.");
                }
                break;
            }   
            
        }
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function generate()
            var pass1="abcd";
            var pass2="1234";
            var pass3="!@#$";
    </script>
    <body>
    <center>
    <p>Generate password token</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Create password" id="password1" readonly />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Create password" id="password2" readonly />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Create password" id="password3" readonly />
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Generate Token" onclick="generate()">
    <p>Enter password token below to continue:</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="getToken">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Validate Token" onclick="validate()">
    </center>
    </body>
```

So I tried doing this but it did not work

```
function generate()

var pass1 = "abcd";
var pass2 = "1234";
var pass3 = "!@#$";

getElementById(password).innerHtml = pass1;
getElementById(passwords).innerHtml = pass2;
getElementById(passwordss).innerHtml = pass3;
```

Oh my God I figured it out So the correct one is

```
<script>


function generate(){

    var pass1 = "abcd";
    var pass2 = "1234";
    var pass3 = "!@#$";

    document.getElementById("password").value=pass1;
    document.getElementById("passwords").value=pass2;
    document.getElementById("passwordss").value=pass3;
}
</script>
```

I changed Innerhtml to value and I was missing {}

Comment: I'm pretty sure the if with `counter==0` will never be true since the while loop doesn't go below 1. Also, please avoid using `document.write`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<h1><center>Hi! there, to enter to our website please generate your Three(3) password token and use it to Enter<center></h1>
</head>
<script>
var counter=3;
function validate()
{
    while(counter>=1)
    {
        var token1="abcd";
        var token2="1234";
        var token3="!@#$";
        var checkToken=document.getElementById("getToken").value;
        if(checkToken===token1 || checkToken===token2)
        {
            document.write("<center>password correct. Please click the link:");
            document.write('<br> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SLU.LJHS">Check our site</a>');
        }
        else
        {
            counter=counter-1;
            alert("Incorrect password!\n\n Attempts left: "+counter);
            if(counter==0)
            {
            document.write("please contact our security team.");
            }
            break;
        }   
        
    }
}
</script>

<script>


function generate(){

    var pass1 = "abcd";
    var pass2 = "1234";
    var pass3 = "!@#$";

    document.getElementById("password").value=pass1;
    document.getElementById("passwords").value=pass2;
    document.getElementById("passwordss").value=pass3;
}
</script>
<body>
<center>
<p>Generate password token</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Create password" id="password" readonly />
<input type="text" placeholder="Create password" id="passwords" readonly />
<input type="text" placeholder="Create password" id="passwordss" readonly />
<br>
<input type="button" value="Generate Token" onclick="generate()">
<p>Enter password token below to continue:</p>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="getToken">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Validate Token" onclick="validate()">
</center>
</body>
```